# Incorrect expected output as " 3 3" instead "3 5" using max and min from Streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, functional-interface

I have the following code

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
li.add(3);li.add(5);
Stream at = li.stream();
Optional<Integer> o = at.min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
if (o.isPresent()) {System.out.println(o.get());}
Stream gt = li.stream();
Optional<Integer> i = gt.max(Comparator.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(i.get());
```

Why I was getting the output as " 3 3" instead "3 5". Please clarify.

Comment: The max of reverse order — the last element in the reverse order — is the min.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind it is the `Comparator` used. You are reversing the elements after sorting while getting the `max` out of them. Of course, the
the reverse of `max` is the `min` and you get the same result.

The solution would be to replace

```
Optional<Integer> i = gt.max(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

with

```
Optional<Integer> i = gt.max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

---

On a slightly different aspect, when you are looking for both `max` and `min` from an integer stream at the same time, you can use summary statistics from the JDK. This looks something like -

```
IntSummaryStatistics statistics = li.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).summaryStatistics();
int max = statistics.getMax();
int min = statistics.getMin();
```

Comment: So Max and Min method as per my Qn, does it refer to the Maximum Value or the Value in the maximum position?

Comment: @mpmuthu It means the maximum value and not the value at the max index.